# Как вывести эту часть кода в файл?

Tags: python, вывод

https://pastebin.com/0g7RgTGA - это весь код, а теперь к проблеме:
как полностью вывести строку 55 в txtфайл? Там должна быть табличка из значений, выводит только ее последнюю строчку.
Строка 63- это моя попытка ее вывести. В Командной строке всё выводится нормально.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Функция `print` - это функция вывода в консоль. Чтобы вывести это в файл, нужно сделать так:

```py
with open("test.txt", "w", encoding='utf-8') as f:
    f.write(f'{bi}')
    f.write(f'\n')
    f.write(f'{entropy}')
    f.write(f'\n')
    for keys,values in m_sort.items():
        a="{}\t{}".format(keys,values)
        f.write(a + '\n')
```

Можно через `print`:

```py
# выводим словарь
for keys,values in m_sort.items():
    a="{}\t{}".format(keys,values)
    print(a)
 
with open("test.txt", "w", encoding='utf-8') as f:
    f.write(f'{bi}')
    f.write(f'\n')
    f.write(f'{entropy}')
    f.write(f'\n')
    r keys,values in m_sort.items():
        a="{}\t{}".format(keys,values)
        print(a + '\n', file=f)
```